# pre tag text not coming in innerText

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was just testing something and noticed that text inside `pre` tag does not appear if you access it using `parent` element.

Following is the code example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/2wkvvapn/)

```js
(function() {
  var _innerText = document.getElementById("content").innerText;
  var _innerHTML = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
  var _textContent = document.getElementById("content").textContent;

  console.log(_innerText, _innerHTML, _textContent)

  console.log($("#content").text());
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="content">
  p text
  <pre>Pre text</pre>
  <small>small text</small>
</p>
```

I also noticed that anything after it is also not fetched. If you move `small` before `pre`, text appears. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ — start by writing real HTML.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot nest block-level elements, such as `<pre>`, inside `<p>` in HTML. Your code block rendered as following in browser.

```
<p id="content"> p text </p>
<pre>Pre text</pre>
<small>small text</small>
<p></p>
```

You can use `div` instead of `p`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't put "pre" in "p" tag, try "div":

```
<div id="content">
  p text
  <pre>Pre text</pre>
  <small>small text</small>
</div>
```